# Google auth - allow user to switch account

Tags: javascript, google-authentication

I am using https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js for google sign in.

The problem I have is that after a user signs in, they will not be able to select a different account/email to sign in with, even after signing out, since when they sign in again it automatically selects the account they chose before.

Here is my code:

```
HTML (pug):

div(id="sign-in-out-nav")
   div(class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn")
   a(href="#" onclick="signOut();") Sign out

JavaScript:

function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  const name = profile.getName();
  const email = profile.getEmail();
  const id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  sendTokenAndVerify(id_token)
  .then((data) => {
    if(data.error || data.success === false){
      return signOut(data.message || "Token could not be verified.");
    }
  })
  //...more code...
}
```

I also have a button which allows them to sign out.

---

How do I allow the user to switch accounts?